# How to create regex for time with AM/PM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to create a regex for getting only time time in javascript ?

```
[12/21/2015 1:00:42.016 AM]
```

I am trying to get

> 1:00 AM (ie HH:MM AM/PM)

This is what i tried

```
input.match(/\d+/g) // => [12,21,2015,1,00,42,016]
```

AM/PM is missing from the result /

Comment: It may be simpler for you to use an existing library, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done quite simply without the use of a RegExp or library.

```js
var s = '[12/21/2015 1:00:42.016 AM]';
var p = s.split(' ').slice(1);
p[0] = p[0].slice(0, p[0].lastIndexOf(':'));
p = p.join(' ').slice(0, -1);
document.body.textContent = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d{1,2}:\d{2}):\d{2}\.\d+ ([AP]M)
```

Now group one will contain the time and group two - AM/PM

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/sL8oS4/1)

---

```
timeRegex = /(\d{1,2}:\d{2}):\d{2}\.\d+ ([AP]M)/;
found = "[12/21/2015 1:00:42.016 AM]".match(timeRegex);
console.log(found[1]); // => "1:00"
console.log(found[2]); // => "AM"
```